Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
My team and I have been encountering this issue for a couple of months already. When running our automated tests (Robotframework) in gitlab (on a docker image), some suites fail sporadically with the following error:
Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
(failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
(Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.224)
As a consequence, the rest of the suite fails as well. Failure occurs on an attempt to capture a screenshot (within the Setup of the suite, for example).
Could anyone shed more light on how to debug this and on a possible solution?
Some more info on the environment:
bcrypt==4.1.3
cffi==1.15.1
cryptography==41.0.3
paramiko==3.0.0
setuptools==68.0.0
pycparser==2.21
PyNaCl==1.5.0
robotframework==6.0.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.0.0
robotframework-sshlibrary==3.6.0
scp==0.14.4
selenium==4.10.0
six==1.16.0

We also use latest chromium and chromium-driver
We have not tried anything yet, as we are not really sure about the origin of the problem. The only possible solution we've found was (hypothetically) downgrading to an older chromium/chromium-driver version. However, this was not accepted as a possible solution.

Is the docker image that of the selenium-docker project?
